# is it possible to put a method(s) in a while loop and or if statements?

Tags: objective-c

trying to convert from java to objective-c. im havin a hard time finding anything on this subject.i get error "semantic issue" cant figure it out.
here's the code:

```
-(void) createColorPalatte{
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    colorPalatte[i] = [self getRandomColor];
}}
-(BOOL) checkColorPalatte {
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (int j=i+1; j<4; j++) {
        if ([getColorFroemPalatte[i]]==[getColorFromPalatte[j]] ) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
return NO;
```

}

```
-(void) redoColorPalatte {
while (YES==[checkColorPalatte];) {
    [createColorPalatte];
}
```

}

```
-(char) getColorFromPalatte: (int) index{
return colorPalatte[index];
```

}

Comment: here is a nice converter **[from Java to Objective C](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the target for your method as well, i.e. which instance it is called on. And of course use `:` instead of `[]` for the arguments.

`[self checkColorPalette]` and `[self getColorFromPalette:i]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fixes I can see in the methods you've posted:

```
-(BOOL) checkColorPalatte {
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (int j=i+1; j<4; j++) {
        if ([self getColorFromPalatte:i]==[self getColorFromPalatte:j] ) { // CHANGED Froem typo and changed [getColorFromPalette[i]] to [self getColorFromPalette:i]
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
return NO;
}

-(void) redoColorPalatte {
while (YES==[self checkColorPalatte]) { // changed [checkColorPalatte]; to [self getColorPalatte]
    [self createColorPalatte]; // ADDED 'self'
}
}
```

Basically remember the convention of `[object method]` or `[object methodArg: value]` where in Java it would be more like `object.method()` or `object.method(value)`

Also, Palette as in colours is spelt "palette" (not a bug but a spelling mistake).